# Transferring HTML element values, to other files

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this piece of code from *first.html*

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<a href="second.html">Go to next page</a>
```

How can I make it that when you go to *second.html*, javascript alerts the value of [name] from *first.html* **OR** the html adds an h1 tag with the value of [name] from *first.html*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementById()` function to get input and access it's `value` property to read what was entered there.

The `onclick` attribute on your anchor element will execute a custom function which will take the href property of the anchor and append the url-encoded value of the input field.

Then it will go to that new URL.

The `return false` ensures that built-in href event does not execute.

```js
function link(anchor) {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value
  var url = anchor.href + "?name=" + encodeURIComponent(name);
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
<a href="second.html" onclick="link(this); return false;">Go to next page</a>
```

To read the passed in variable on the receiving page, use the technique described in this SO post:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks, but when i want to alert it in second.html, the javascript alert box is empty

Comment: You can use the technique described in this SO article to read passed in query string variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you could use onclick function on anchor  tag.

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<a onclick="goToNextPage()">Go to next page</a>
<script>
function goToNextPage()
{
var value = document.getElementById('name').value;
 window.location.href="second.html?name="+value;
}
</script>
```

Or you could use form.submit() to post the form values to request.

As HTML is only markup language, not programming language. So, you would need either php/ javascript to fetch that value on second page.

```
function qs(search_for) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var parms = query.split('&');
        for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
            var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
            if (pos > 0  && search_for == parms[i].substring(0,pos)) {
                return parms[i].substring(pos+1);;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

and then call that function in your second page as.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(qs("name"));
</script>
```